# Laravel + Angular routing

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel/Angular AJAX integration :

I can directly go into my laravel routing by putting it on my own but Angular AJAX doesn't work. This is what I get from my browser console :

GET path to my laravel route (Not Found) angular.js:8611

Comment: Please show your routing config, and the actual URL that's being called.

Comment: You should your routing config of both Laravel and AngularJS

Comment: Best way to work with both Laravel and AngularJS at the same time is to let Laravel run an `api.domain.tld` prefix, and AngularJS a `domain.tld` prefix. This will keep both Laravel and AngularJS routing apart from each other. Then, when you need data from Laravel storage (database etc.) call the `api` path from AngularJS to receive a JSON response from Laravel.

Comment: <?php
Route::get('/', function()
{
 return View::make('layout');
});
Route::get('/api/products', 'HomeController@products');
Route::get('/api/items/total', 'HomeController@total');
Route::get('/api/items', 'HomeController@alist');
Route::post('/api/items', 'HomeController@create');
Route::put('/api/items/{name}', 'HomeController@update');
Route::delete('/api/items/{name}', 'HomeController@del');

Comment: ShopApp.factory('Items', function($http) {

    return {
      get: function() { return $http.get('/api/items'); },
     post: function(product) { return $http.post('/api/items', product); },
      put: function(name, changes) { return $http.put('/api/items/'+name, changes); },
      del: function(name) { return $http.delete('/api/items/'+name); }
    };
  });